# Проблема в передачи правильного id объекта

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mvc

снова возник вопрос по RYBU. Собственно в чем состояла задача, имеется форма со списком задач, вот такого вида

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

При клике на чекбокс нужно чтобы это изменение заносилось в БД, то есть если флажок стоял, а я его снимаю, то в БД нужно чтобы обновлялось с true на false, при этом без перехода на вьюху редактирования. Я это реализовал костыльно, знаю, просто метода лучше не нашел. Собственно, как я это реализовал:

```
           <ul>
            <%= project.todos.find_each do |todo| %>
            <%= form_for :todo, url: todo_path(todo), :html =>{:id => "form-check"} do |form| %>
              <%= form.text_field :text, {:value => todo.text, :style => "display:none"} %>
              <%= form.check_box :isCompleted, {:checked => todo.isCompleted, :class => "icheck-me check_test", 'data-color' => "blue", 'data-skin' => "square"} %>
              <%= form.text_field :project_id, {:value => todo.project_id, :style => "display:none"} %>
            <% end %>
            <li><%= todo.text %></li>
            <%end%>
          </ul>
```

И повесил сабмит на чекбокс:

```
                  $('.check_test').on('ifUnchecked', function(event) {
                        event.preventDefault();
                        $('#form-check').submit();
                    });

                    $('.check_test').on('ifChecked', function(event) {
                        event.preventDefault();
                        $('#form-check').submit();
                    });
```

Вот так форма выглядит в браузере:

```
        <form id="form-check" action="/todos/14" accept-charset="UTF-8" method="post"><input name="utf8" type="hidden" value="&#x2713;" /><input type="hidden" name="authenticity_token" value="SBVsnDR/Ppqnt4jFETaWKLq5hQmrsh9+0eH9aka23akeYCVLXySIftXU0RwUiLtko0fqQah9ooG28spPA0tJRA==" />
          <input value="Купить молоко" style="display:none" type="text" name="todo[text]" id="todo_text" />
          <input name="todo[isCompleted]" type="hidden" value="0" /><input class="icheck-me check_test" data-color="blue" data-skin="square" type="checkbox" value="1" name="todo[isCompleted]" id="todo_isCompleted" /> 
          <input value="10" style="display:none" type="text" name="todo[project_id]" id="todo_project_id" />
```

**Причем у каждого чекбокса разный id в action(/todos/id).**

Вот контроллер Todo:

```
class TodosController < ApplicationController
        before_action :set_todo, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

        def index
          @todos = Todo.all
        end

        def new
          @todo = Todo.new
        end

        def create
          @todo = Todo.new(todo_params)
          respond_to do |format|
            if @todo.save
              format.html {redirect_to projects_url }
            end
          end
        end

        def update
          respond_to do |format|
            if @todo.update(todo_params)
              format.html {redirect_to projects_url}
            end
          end
        end

        def destroy
          @todo.destroy
          respond_to do |format|
            format.html {redirect_to projects_url}
          end
        end

        private
          def set_todo
            @todo = Todo.find(params[:id])
          end

          def todo_params
            params.require(:todo).permit(:text, :isCompleted, :project_id)
          end
      end
```

Вот модель Todo:

```
            class Todo < ApplicationRecord
              belongs_to :project, optional: true
            end
```

Вот Рауты:

```
            Rails.application.routes.draw do
                root 'projects#index'

              resources :projects, :todos
            end
```

Вот сама вьюха целиком:

```
<div class="container">
      <div class="row">
          <%= Project.find_each do |project| %>
            <div class="col-lg-4 col-lg-offset-0 col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-0 col-xs-10 col-xs-offset-1">
                <div class="box">
                  <div class="box-wrapper">
                    <h2 class="box-wrapper-header text-left">
                      <%= project.title %>
                    </h2>
                    <hr>
                    <ul>
                      <%= project.todos.find_each do |todo| %>
                      <%= form_for :todo, url: todo_path(todo), :html =>{:id => "form-check"} do |form| %>
                        <%= form.text_field :text, {:value => todo.text, :style => "display:none"} %>
                        <%= form.check_box :isCompleted, {:checked => todo.isCompleted, :class => "icheck-me check_test", 'data-color' => "blue", 'data-skin' => "square"} %>
                        <%= form.text_field :project_id, {:value => todo.project_id, :style => "display:none"} %>
                      <% end %>
                      <li><%= todo.text %></li>
                      <%end%>
                    </ul>
                  </div>
                </div>
            </div>
          <%end%>
        </div>
      </div>
```

Проблема состоит в том, что при клике на чекбокс всегда перебрасывает перебрасывает на страницу редактирования первого элемента, то есть на задачу купить молоко. И можно ли как-то не переходить на вьюху редактирования, а все делать на главной странице?

Answer (score 0):

Вы сабмитите форму по айдишнику, а он у всех форм одинаковый `#form-check`, поэтому отправляется всегда первая форма. Вам надо поправить jQuery, чтобы отправлялась нужная форма, что-то вроде `this.parent('#form-check').submit()`.

Чтобы форма работала на той же странице, к ней надо добавить `remote: true`, и в контроллере обрабатывать format.js

Comment: не особо понятно про id, происходит же отправка данных по action, а он у всех разный, при parent он будет обращаться к родителю, который ul

Comment: @ЯнСоколиков, отправка данных у вас совершенно верно происходит, у вас форма ищется неправильно. Независимо от того, на какой чекбокс вы кликаете, `$('#form-check')` вам вернёт что? Правильно, самую первую форму, она и отправляется. Вам jQuery надо поправить, чтобы уходила именно та форма, в которой вы ставите галочку. jQuery - не моя сильная сторона, поэтому точно я вам не подскажу, как его написать

Comment: хорошо, я Вас понял, с jquery я справлюсь. Единственное, что флажок с true на false и наоборот не меняется даже на 1 форме, то есть изменение в БД не происходит, я так понимаю просто не передается параметр сновым значением, или я не прав?

Comment: Да вообще иметь несколько элементов с одинаковыми `id` на одной странице [не очень нормально](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/id).

Comment: @ЯнСоколиков, чтобы менялся флажок, вам нужно создать вьюху `update.js`, в которой вы и будете его менять - http://guides.rubyonrails.org/working_with_javascript_in_rails.html А чтобы понять, чего у вас в БД происходит, нужны логи